# Generate certain lists based on values in 2 seperate Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to generate certain lists based on 2 cell values. for example if x = 45 and y = 70 generate a list. This is the formula I have come up with but it is too long to be put into a data validation source. Is there an easier way I can do this?

```
=IF(AND($K$23 ="Capital Area", $L$23="Vodafone4G"), CAVodafone4G, IF(AND($K$23 ="Capital Area", $L$23 = "Vodafone5G"), CAVodafone5G,  IF(AND($K$23 ="Capital Area", $L$23 = "Optus4G"),CAOptus4G, IF(AND($K$23 ="Capital Area", $L$23 = "Optus5G"),CAOptus5G, IF(AND($K$23 ="Capital Area", $L$23 = "Telstra4G"), CATelstra4G, IF(AND($K$23 ="Capital Area", $L$23 = "Telstra5G"), CATeltra5G, IF(AND($K$23 ="Regional Area", $L$23="Vodafone4G"), RAVodafone4G, IF(AND($K$23 ="Regional Area", $L$23 = "Vodafone5G"), RAVodafone5G,  IF(AND($K$23 ="Regional Area", $L$23 = "Optus4G"),RAOptus4G, IF(AND($K$23 ="Regional Area", $L$23 = "Optus5G"),RAOPtus5G, IF(AND($K$23 ="Regional Area", $L$23 = "Telstra4G"), RATelstra4G, IF(AND($K$23 ="Regional Area", $L$23 = "Telstra5G"), RATeltra5G))))))))))))
```

Please help haha :)

Thanks

Comment: Put few sample data and list you want to generate from those sample data.

Comment: Why not create a list of combinations and outcome and use index match or vlookup?

Comment: Maybe, for validation, use dependent dropdown lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like:

```
=IF($K$23 ="Capital Area";"CA";if($K$23 = "Regional Area";"RA"))&$L$23
```

You only want two conditions, and the rest is just a concatenation.